# How to calc square root in stylus

Tags: stylus

Is there a way to get Stylus calculate the square root of `x`?
You know, like JavaScript's `Math.sqrt(x)` does.

I am creating a diamond that should be centered on it's origin. the following code am i using at the moment:

```
vendor(prop, args...)
    -webkit-{prop} args
    -moz-{prop} args
    -o-{prop} args
    -ms-{prop} args


rotate(r)
    vendor('transform', unquote('rotate('+r+')'))
    rotate r


.diamond
    display block

    width 7ex
    height @width
    line-height @height
    rotate(-45deg)

    /* calc offset of a rotated square
     * @width * @width = $offsetX * $offsetX + $offsetY * $offsetY
     * @width * @width = ( $offset * $offset ) * 2 // for a square: $offsetX= $offsetY
     * ( @width * @width ) / 2 = ( $offset * $offset )
     * sqrt(( @width * @width ) / 2) = $offset
     * @width * sqrt(2) = $offset
     */
    $offset = @width / 1.41421356237 // =sqrt( 2 )
    margin (- $offset) 0em 0ex (- $offset ) // center the diamond on its origin

    padding 0ex 0em

    background-color red
```

as you can see, i managed to work it out without actually calculating the square root, but using a constant value instead.
But when I looked at the [Built-in Functions of Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html), I was unable to find any method to calculate the square root.

Is there any way to get stylus calculate the square root of `x`?
<sub>Of cause the best would be to have some nice functions like [LESS has built in.](http://lesscss.org/#reference)</sub>

Comment: how to teach math to stylus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113212

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [answered there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21196671/885556) you can use the built-in `math` function for this, so the custom `sqrt` could look better:

```
sqrt(x)
  return math(x, 'sqrt')
```

Comment: Can you pass multiple args to math functions? I'm trying to do `pow` https://gist.github.com/corysimmons/9d4c482397317bb6378a but it errors out. Will I just have to loop over space separated vals?

Comment: Stylus has pow [operator](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/operators.html#exponent-) from the box: `4 ** 3` :) And there are no other Math methods where we'd need more that one argument in math func.

Comment: lol, I'm so stupid. I completely knew about the exponent operator. Was way too tired when I wrote that comment. Thanks again Kizu. =)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
sqrt(x)
  if x == 0
    result = 0
  else
    result = 4
    for i in (0..10)
      result = ((result + (x / result)) / 2)
```

Demo on codepen: http://cdpn.io/jcnLF